# Android Programmig (Eclipse)

Tags: android

While creating a project on eclipse i got these error in R.java file.
Multiple markers at this line
    - Duplicate field R.string.row
    - Syntax error on token "four", delete 
     this token

Comment: Can you show the specific line where you get the error?

Comment: Getting error on R.java file on eclipse.

Comment: I need the line in `R.java`

Comment: You have a string defined twice

Comment: public static final int row four=0x7f0a0017;
        public static final int row one=0x7f0a0014;
        public static final int row three=0x7f0a0016;
        public static final int row two=0x7f0a0015;
        public static final int yellow=0x7f0a0010;

Comment: I added that as an answer, so that you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code, as per your comment:

```
public static final int row four=0x7f0a0017;
public static final int row one=0x7f0a0014;
public static final int row three=0x7f0a0016;
public static final int row two=0x7f0a0015;
public static final int yellow=0x7f0a0010;
```

You c**an't use spaces** in object (or variables, constants, methods, ...) names as in `row one`... use `row_one`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check you **string.xml** file in **values** folder under **res**. Same String defined twice perhaps!